# getElementsByClassName and setAttribute not working

Tags: getelementsbyclassname

I am trying to change the style of a button using java script using getElementsByClassName. It does not seem to work. Firebug gives me a "Not enough arguments - list[index].setAttribute("button");" Error.

Here is what my code looks like:

```
function clear(y){
var list, index;
list = document.getElementsByClassName('button1);
for (index = 0; index < list.length; ++index) {
list[index].setAttribute("button");
}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is self explanatory. You are missing a parameter in the method `setAttribute()`. Add another argument for what you want the new `button` attribute to be.

```
list[index].setAttribute('button', 'myValue');
```

If your intention is to remove the `button` attribute, use `removeAttribute()`.

```
list[index].removeAttribute('button');
```